# Passing Values From Raw Input From Within The Window Procedure

Tags: windows, winapi, input, raw-input

Currently, this is the WM_INPUT case in my Window Procedure (WINDPROC).

```
case WM_INPUT:
{
    // ... Some code to pull out the input from the message
    if(InputType == Keyboard)
    {
        if(KeyCode == KEY_W)
        {
             // Do Stuff Here
        }
    }
 // And so on...
}
```

But, I want to be able to do the following...

```
if(KeyCode == KEY_W)
{
    g_InputManager->PressKey(KEY_W);
}
```

So that my game engine knows when a key is pressed, I would like to know how to get data in/out of the window procedure, or how to process raw input outside of the window procedure.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can get data in/out of the window procedure by calling a function and passing the data as a parameter. It's not really clear to me what the second code snippet is intended to convey. You can't actually receive notifications other than through the window procedure, that's how event-driven Windows programming works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a pretty simple question and I see that now, all I did was make a global class pointer, exposed it to the window procedure, and then used it to push data to the external class.